# Remove previous query strings on router redirect

Tags: aurelia

My aurelia application has two roots, an app-login and the app root. When users try to access the application and are not logged in, they are sent to the app-login route, which only has 1 route configured, `login`.

If an unauthenticated user tries to access the app as though they were logged in, (e.g. `localhost:3000/#/needsAuthenticationRoute`), I want the user to be taken to the login page, however, upon successfully logging in, have them be redirect to the page they were initially trying to access.

I try to handle the issue as follows:

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes((instruction) => {
  let redirectUrl = 'login';
  console.log(instruction);

  if(instruction.fragment !== '/') {
    let redirect = instruction.fragment;
    if(instruction.queryString) {
      redirect = redirect + '?' + instruction.queryString;
    }
    redirectUrl = router.generate('login', {redirect});
  }
  return {redirect: redirectUrl };
});
```

So from the app-login route, if they try to access `needsAuthenticationRoute`, they would be redirected back to the login page with a redirect parameter (the user would be sent to `localhost:3000/#/login?redirect=%2FneedsAuthenticationRoute` in this case).

However, when the user tries to access a route with a query string (e.g. `needsAuthenticationRoute?param=value`), I would want the user to be redirected to `localhost:3000/#/login?redirect=%2FneedsAuthenticationRoute%3Fparam%3Dvalue`. However, the redirect keeps around the query parameter and I am left with a route that looks like
`localhost:3000/#/login?redirect=%2FneedsAuthenticationRoute%3Fparam%3Dvalue?param=value`.

Does anybody know how to clear query the query params when specifying a redirect instruction? Or have an alternative solution to what I am proposing?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently just implemented the exact functionality you describe (I also have a blog post in draft about this topic too - when I get round to publishing it...)

I have a bunch of routes, some that have query strings, some which don't. If the user isn't logged in i want to redirect them to the login page, then after successful login I want to redirect them to where they were going before.

Also, I wanted to keep the "?returnUrl=" query string out of the url, it works, but just felt a bit messy to me - considering that this is all client side routing, i knew i could store it somewhere and "hide" it/

So firstly, we need to stash the route they were going to before login, this is done in a defined AuthorizeStep [Aurelia AuthorizeStep](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/securing-your-app/2)

```
@inject(MyApi)
class AuthorizeStep implements PipelineStep {
    constructor(private api: MyApi) { }

    public run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): Promise<any> {
        if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.settings.roles.indexOf("Client") !== -1)) {
            if (!this.api.LoggedIn && navigationInstruction.config.name !== "login") {
                this.api.RouteFragment = navigationInstruction.fragment;
                return next.cancel(new Redirect("login"));
            }
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

Finally, the login page needs to be made aware that after logging in, the user might be going somewhere. So after a successful login we check to see if anything has been stashed in the RouteFragment

```
if (loginResult.Success) {
    if (this.api.RouteFragment && this.api.RouteFragment.length > 0) {
        // Navigate to where the user was trying to go before Logging In
        this.router.navigate(this.api.RouteFragment);
    } else {
        this.router.navigate("/dashboard");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't address my problem which is with the query params.

I can successfully redirect routes with no issues when there are no query. However, my problem exists when there are query params in the route the unauthenticated user tries to access.

Comment: you want to keep the query params and they're currently being thrown away?

Comment: So the problem is that the query params are NOT being thrown away on redirect. And basically being counted twice.

Also, your solution isn't compatible with my set-up.

My login-app root, only has the login route defined, so if I try to hit an unknown route, the authorization step doesn't fire :(

Comment: ah right, i think you may have to go with something crude and search the string and delete everything after (and including) the '?'

Comment: The workaround I came up with was, to create another route called `login redirect`, which matches on /login/{:redirectRoute}.

So instead of trying to redirect with the `localhost:3000/#/login?redirect=%2FneedsAuthenticationRoute%3Fparam%3Dvalue`, it would now become `localhost:3000/#/login/needsAuthenticationRoute?param=value`.

Not exactly the way I wanted to solve it, but it is what it is